# Grep a specific word in a single string with repetitions

Tags: bash, grep

How can I grep a specific word in a single string that contains repetitions?

For example :

```
Apple_1 Apple_1_Test Juice_2 Juice_2_H
```

If I use `grep -Eo 'Apple_1'` I get two results (because of two Apple_1 in the original string)

But what if I want to grep only the perfect word `Apple_1` and not `Apple_1_Test` or `Juice_2` and not `Juice_2_H`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a word boundary assertion:

```
grep -Eo '\bApple_1\b'
```

Comment: Option **-w** is enough: `grep -Ewo 'Apple_1'`

Comment: Perfect in either way :-D
Thank you very much

Comment: @GabryRome If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.